# How to load again(reload) component in VueJs or destroy it and load again?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, quasar-framework

I have a component in VueJs such as Aplayer(or any other components) for playing audio and managing playlist on it.

Now I need to reload it when I change the playlist without changing the routes. is there any way to reload a component or destroy it then load it immediately?

I want to change the playlist of [this](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer) component while it playing music, but sometimes it plays the music of the previous playlist and I don't know why.

HTML segment:

```
<aplayer autoplay
  ref="remote"
  :music="music_list[0]"
  :list="music_list"
  :float="float"
  :mutex="mutex"
  repeat="list"
  :mini="mini"
  preload="auto"
  @ended="onEnd"
  @loadstart="playCMD"
  @playing="onStart"
  :listFolded="listFolded"
  :controls="controls"
  :muted.sync="muted"
  :volume.sync="volume"
  slot="display"
/>
```

JavaScript segment:

```
export default {
  components: {
    Aplayer
  },
  data: () => ({
    float: false,
    autoplay: true,
    mutex: true,
    muted: false,
    volume: 0.8,
    mini: false,
    listFolded: false,
    controls: true,
    music_list: [..]
  }),
  methods: {
    onEnd: function () {
      // Doing a series of jobs that leads to raising an event then
      this.music_list = [new music list after event trigger]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to reload the component? If you are binding your data correctly, you shouldn't have to reload the entire thing. Seems like a performance concern. Vue's reactivity system should be able to pickup all changes you need (if being used correctly), without having to refresh anything. I think that [this resource](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render) has everything that you are looking for

Comment: @EvanBechtol Thank you so much. Because the component that I used for my project has some bugs that it works fine when I change my routes.

Comment: No problem, that's the down-side of 3rd-party sometimes ;)
Did the linked resource help you out?

Comment: @EvanBechtol I want to change the playlist of [this](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer) component while it playing music, but sometimes it plays the music of the previous playlist and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you please update your question by attaching the relevant code?

Comment: Yes, I added some code there. I expect to execute my new `music_list` not run the previous `music_list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your changes are not being picked up is because you *(or the player component)* are not utilizing Vue's reactivity system properly. You should be using [the appropriate array mutation method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) so that [array reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) is maintained. **Vue will not pickup changes made directly to array elements**.

Meaning, when you do something like:

```js
this.myArray[1] = "some new value";
```

Those changes will **not** be picked up by Vue.

---

#### The correct way to manipulate an array in Vue

Using your `onEnd` method, Try changing the code to this....

```js
onEnd: function () {
  // Assumption: resultOfSomeJob is an array of songs for the playlist
  
  // Clear our playlist
  this.music_list = [];

  // Push elements to our music_list using the Vue array method "push"
  this.music_list.push(...resultOfSomeJob);
}
```

#### Edit:

I took a look at the `aplayer` component code. The reason my answer works is because it takes the `:list` that you give it, and [computes a new property](https://github.com/SevenOutman/vue-aplayer/blob/654425f3bfcf7fd348edf6d6e994a5cfef33182b/src/vue-aplayer.vue#L302), `musicList`.

*(Here is the code in case it changes in the future)*

```js
musicList () {
  return this.list
}
```

I found [this excerpt](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) from the Vue docs pretty helpful in understanding what's going on here...

> computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.

So, when you change your array without using the proper methods to maintain reactivity and then it is passed to the `a-player` component, the **computed property is not updated**. Thus, your old playlist remains :)

Comment: Your answer is very useful, but I don't know why this didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean that my answer didn't solve the problem? I think that the way you were doing it didn't work because of how the `<aplayer>` component is utilizing the array. More than likely it's doing stuff outside the Vue reactivity scope. So, when you reset the `music_list` array like I did in my answer it resets the data structure in that component

Comment: Your answer was true, I'm looking for the bug in the `Aplayer`. Also, I'm using from `$refs` to check what music is playing right now. The `$refs` property is realtime?

Comment: @AliHallaji I have updated my answer, with the bug in the component

Comment: I appreciate you. So I should put the musicList in my code?

Comment: I wouldn't put it in your code. How you are doing it is correct actually. The bug is due to the component's computed property `musicList` being cached.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest hack, just use `v-if`:

```
<aplayer v-if='loaded' />
```

script

```
export default {
  components: { Aplayer },
  data: () => ({
    loaded: true,
  }),
  methods: {
    onEnd: function () {
      // when you want to reload the component just make `loaded = false`
      this.loaded = false;
      // load agin with `setTimeout` or promise 
      // or with your logic - whenever the component is ready to show
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.loaded = true
      }, 500); // delay in ms
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean, nice approach!